# First Point hidden by y-axis in datetime graph when container is responsive

Tags: highcharts, responsive-design

http://jsfiddle.net/vUdGJ/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts(
    {
    "xAxis": {
        "startOnTick": true,
        "endOnTick": true,
        "type": "datetime",
          "min": Date.UTC(2014, 1, 2),
          "max": Date.UTC(2014, 4, 31)
    },
    "series": [{
        "type": "line",
        "data": [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0), 30],
            [Date.UTC(2014, 1, 3, 11, 0, 0, 0), 24],

        ],
    }]
    }
    );
});
```

If you drag the divider to the left, the first point disappears behind the y-axis.

The model could not be much simpler. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by setting `startOnTick: true`. As you can see, the first tick on a chart is 3rd of Feb (even if you specify to be 2nd of a Feb). Simply remove that option and will be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vUdGJ/1/

Comment: I think that that is a work around, and that it still may be a bug.

However, I shall go with that. 

Thanks, Neil

Comment: Another solution is to remove `min`. `startOnTick` then may be set to true.